# How to return TRUE with time()?

Tags: php

How to return TRUE when an account was created more than 30 days ago?

I have the following date:

`$udata['joined'];` - record date in time():

I tried like this

```
If($udata['joined'] = strtotime ("+30 days", time())){
    return true;
}
```

Any idea why it's not working correctly?

Return empty.

Comment: A single `=` is an assignment [operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php). For readability, I would utilise converting it to a `DateTime` object and then using the inbuilt `diff` method. [See an example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hIWtT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want

`If timestamp is smaller than (or exactly) 30 days ago`

```
if ($udata['joined'] <= strtotime("-30 days", time()) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

(you need to substract 30 days from now and remove all syntax errors)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a value instead of using an [operator](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp), i.e. you are using `=` instead of `==`. Try this:

```
If($udata['joined'] == strtotime ("+30 days", time())){
    return true;
}
```

#### Edit

As others pointed out, checking for equality will most likely always return false anyway, because you'd be very luck to hit the exact same timestamp!

What you are looking for is the `<=` (less than or equal) operator to check if `$udata['joined']` is a timestamp *before* `30 days ago`. In other words :

```
// true if the provided date is before 30 days ago
return strtotime($udata['joined']) < strtotime("-30 days", time());
```